# Update user profile with user uuid

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-views

I want to update user profile passing user uuid as kwarg.
Here is the url:

```
path("profile/update/<uuid:pk>", UpdateProfile.as_view(), name="update_profile"),
```

However, after I try to update my profile, it gives me an error.
Here is my view:

```
class UpdateProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    user_type_fields = {
        "Buyer": ["photo", "first_name", "last_name", "city"],
        "Celler": ["photo", "name", "city", "address"],
    }

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        self.fields = self.user_type_fields[get_user_model().objects.get(pk=kwargs["pk"]).type]
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And here is the error itself:

```
Page not found (404)
No profile found matching the query
```

As I understand, django tries to find profile with uuid as in url, doesn't find it and returns me this error. However, if I change model in my view to user, it wouldn't be able to find fields as they belong to profile model. The only working option was to pass profile id as kwarg, but I don`t find it preferrable due to security reasons.

Could someone give me an advice on how to update profile with user uuid in kwargs?
Thanks in advance!

UPD:
Here are User and Profile models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class UserTypeChoices(models.TextChoices):
        SINGLE_VOLUNTEER = "Single Volunteer", _("Single Volunteer")
        VOLUNTEERS_ORGANISATION = "Volunteers Organisation", _("Volunteers Organisation")
        CIVIL_PERSON = "Civil Person", _("Civil Person")
        MILITARY_PERSON = "Military Person", _("Military Person")

    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=23,
        choices=UserTypeChoices.choices,
    )
    uuid = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
        editable=False,
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        _("email address"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    phone = PhoneNumberField(
        _("phone"),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _("staff status"),
        default=False,
        help_text=_("Designates whether the user can log into this admin site."),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _("active"),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Designates whether this user should be treated as active. " "Unselect this instead of deleting accounts."
        ),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        if self.email:
            return str(self.email)
        else:
            return str(self.phone)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to="accounts.CustomUser", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile/", blank=True, null=True, default="profile/profile_default.png")
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    city = models.CharField(_("city"), max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    address = PlainLocationField()

    def __str__(self):
        if self.user.email:
            return str(self.user.email)
        else:
            return str(self.user.phone)
```

Comment: Can you share your `Profile` model?

Comment: Added it to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following model, where a user only has one profile:

```py
    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        photo = models.ImageField()
        # ... your other fields
```

You can then overwrite the `get_object()` method:

```py
    class UpdateProfile(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
        model = Profile
        fields = ['photo', '...']

        def get_object(self):
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
            profile = user.profile
            return profile
```

And then use the UpdateView as normal.